# Redirect 301 after domain change

Tags: redirect, seo

I had to do a **domain change** on a website so I moved from www.mydomain.it to www.mydomain.eu. At the moment I don't have full control on the .it domain so when it was the time to make the domain change I asked the hosting provider to make a 301 redirect of the .it to the .eu so as a result, I got all the pages of the .it website redirected to my .eu's homepage (no 404 errors) because the previous website used queries as pages' URLs.

This is a link example of the previous website:

```
http://www.mydomain.it/index.php?page=lkr_pg_chisiamo
```

So what I started getting after the redirect was:

```
https://www.mydomain.eu/index.php?page=lkr_pg_chisiamo
```

which gave me back the homepage content as a result and not a 404 error.

The old website had **at least 10k** **links** like that one so each of them started having the behavior of the link above, I got the homepage content for all links. In the beginning, I thought it was a good thing for me because I wasn't getting 404 errors but then I started digging around on the web and I found out to not be a good practice because all links might be recognized as soft 404 errors.

Obviously before I made the domain change I had created all the 301 redirects of the most important pages of the website like this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=lkr_pg_chisiamo$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.eu/chi-siamo/? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^page=lkr_pg_contattaci&form_key=25-8124355$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mydomain.eu/contatti/? [R=301,L]
```

And so on..

Obviously, I didn't do that for all the 10k pages, but just the most important, so the other links are still pointing to the homepage content.

After I did this, I told Google I had changed the domain through the Google Search Console.

After a few weeks, I started seeing some results on Google but after one month I'm not still happy with them, I think I lost rank on Google. I know it could take a while more to do everything and that I should probably lose 3% of my "domain juice" after a domain change but what I was wondering if I have done everything in the right way in order to not lose rank.

My concern now is about all the links that I wasn't able to redirect and that has been redirected automatically and started getting the homepage content. Should I be worried about them?

How should I manage them?

Should I redirect them to another page which is not the homepage?

If yes, is there a way to redirect all those links (just those) even though I have all the other redirects in my .htaccess file?

Was there a better way to redirect all the 10k links of that type? How would I be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You asked this 6 months ago, but i hope i can help you.

Add this to your **.htaccess**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.it$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.eu [R=301,L]
```

This should redirect all links to your new domain.

About Google Search Console, take a look here: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93633?hl=en

About changing domain, look at: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/6033049?hl=en

Hope this helps!

Brhaka